# Strange error during XSL/XML load in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, servlets, web-inf

I understand that any resource under WEB-INF is not in public domain and this is by design.
I can access a resource under WEB-INF, say an HTML, by configuring it in web.xml as

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resourceId</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/resource.xsl</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resourceId</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource.xsl</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But I face a strange situation where, using document creation api on client side i.e document.implementation.createDocument fails shooting a deprecation warning and suggesting XMLHttpRequest instead. I am trying to load and XSL/XML document using this api as follows

```
xmlFile = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
xmlFile.async = false;
xmlFile.load("resource.xsl");
```

And I get a warning:

> Use of Document.load() is deprecated. To upgrade your code, use the DOM XMLHttpRequest object. For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest*

But if I place the resource under WebContent or WebRoot folder directly and remove any web.xml configuration for that, it works smoothly. I do not understand this. I tested this on FF 3.6.5, 5.0.1, 9, 10. Please explain this to me.

I also realize that during failure, i.e when warning shows up due to the resource placed in WEB-INF folder, the browser does succeed in loading despite warning. Firebug shows it. But the XSL or the XML is loaded as text/html and object xmlFile is rather empty and unpopulated. In case of success, I see application/xml in response headers and  xmlFile object nicely populated. Please help

Comment: Important thing to note is that If I place the resource directly under WebContent or WebRoot but make a configuration in web.xml as   <url-pattern>/resource.xsl</url-pattern> implying that it is directly under the root, it still fails. The XSL or XML is loaded as text/html and xmlFile object is unpopulated. If I remove configuration in web.xml, it is a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But the XSL or the XML is loaded as text/html and object xmlFile is rather empty and unpopulated. In case of success, I see application/xml in response headers and xmlFile object nicely populated.*

Apparently the container doesn't check the mime type when the resource is served from `/WEB-INF` by a `web.xml` hack and defaults to `text/html`. The wrong content type explains all the JavaScript errors you're facing.

I'd create a wrapper servlet which explicitly sets the content type and forwards to the XSL resource in the `doGet()` method:

```java
response.setContentType("application/xml");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/resource.xsl").forward(request, response);
```

Map it as follows instead.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resourceId</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.XSLResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resourceId</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource.xsl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Make the `/WEB-INF/resource.xsl` if necessary an `<init-param>` setting so that you can define and configure it in `web.xml` instead of hardcoding in the servlet code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I won't get a response. I checked after a long time and I found it answered. Your answer is very helpful but I am unable to "UP" it by 1 as I don't have 15 points. How do I say "answered" or +1 point?